# How to file income tax returns for profits from ESPP stock?

Tags: income-tax, india, espp

My company is listed on the NASDAQ. I sold stock under its Employee Stock Purchase Plan (ESPP). I want to know how to file income tax returns for the profit.

Which form should I use? What values should I fill in?

Answer (score 1):

Consult a professional CA.

For shares sold outside the Indian Stock Exchanges, these will be treated as normal Long Term Capital Gains if held more than one year. The rate would be 10% without Indexation and 20% with Indexation.

If the stocks are held for less than 1 years, it will be short term gains and taxed according you to tax bracket.

Answer (score 1):

I did this for the last tax year so hopefully I can help you. You should get a 1099-B (around the same time you're getting your W-2(s)) from the trustee (whichever company facilitates the ESPP) that has all the information you need to file. You'll fill out a Schedule D and (probably) a Form 8949 to describe the capital gains and/or losses from your sale(s). It's no different than if you had bought and sold stock with any brokerage.